# How to retrieve the parent node using cElementTree?

Tags: python, celementtree

for the xml

```
<grandparent>
  <parent1>
     <child>data1</child>
  </parent1>
  <parent2>
     <child>data2</child>
  </parent2>
</grandparent>
```

I need the list containing tuples of parent,data for each parent in xml.

Is there a way to do it USING cElementTree? I am able to do it for child,data, but unfortunately child is identical in all the values, hence it is of not much use.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you can get access to the parent from the child using version 1.3 of ElementTree (check http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm), by using xpath commands like  `child.find('../parent')`. But I think python ships with version 1.2 or something.

You should also check for lxml which is compatible with etree and has full Xpath support http://lxml.de/

Comment: The docs says something like `Changed in version 2.7: The ElementTree API is updated to 1.3.` in http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree I'm using 2.7 but for me `'../myparent'` still doesn't seem to work; what does this mean?

Comment: Yes I don't think this is support in cElementTree. e.g.: ET.fromstring("<a><b></b></a>").find('.//b').find('..') returns None

Comment: @AndySmith I think I know why it returns none. The [doc says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) : `Selects the parent element. Returns None if the path attempts to reach the ancestors of the start element (**the element find was called on**).`

Answer (score 6):

```
parent_map = dict((c, p) for p in tree.getiterator() for c in p)
parent_map[el].remove(el)
```

Comment: +1. because in elementTree, accessing parent by `..` is broken or not working or any other way that i don't know.so your way will solve it!!! we can also do it as `{c:p for p in tree.getiterator() for c in p}`

Comment: @namit I can confirm this. I can correctly access my nodes but when I do `print('parent = ', el.findall("../"))` which is how [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) said so, I get null objects.

Comment: @namit turns out I didn't correctly read the documentation for `..`: `Selects the parent element. Returns None if the path attempts to reach the ancestors of the start element (the element find was called on).`[link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

This syntax seemed to work for cElementTree

```
ET.fromstring("<c><a><b></b></a></c>").find('.//b/..')
```

No going to base parent, and using double slash then single slash in path.
(would have posted as a comment to above thread but it seems I have no privilege to)