# access ElementTree node parent node

Tags: python, elementtree

I am using the builtin Python ElementTree module. It is straightforward to access children, but what about parent or sibling nodes? - can this be done efficiently without traversing the entire tree?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374245/how-to-retrieve-the-parent-node-using-celementtree

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There's no direct support in the form of a `parent` attribute, but you can perhaps use the patterns described [here](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm#accessing-parents) to achieve the desired effect. The following one-liner is suggested (updated from the linked-to post to Python 3.8) to create a child-to-parent mapping for a whole tree, using the method [`xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter):

```
parent_map = {c: p for p in tree.iter() for c in p}
```

Comment: Syntax update, 2017 / python3

`parent_map = {(c,p) for p in tree.iter( ) for c in p}`

Comment: Correction:

`parent_map = {c:p for p in root.iter( ) for c in p}`

Comment: What about if you cannot read the whole XML file in one go, but must iterate over a file with iter()?

Answer (score 32):

[Vinay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170994/1556416) should still work, but for Python 2.7+ and 3.2+ the following is recommended:

```
parent_map = {c:p for p in tree.iter() for c in p}
```

`getiterator()` is deprecated in favor of `iter()`, and it's nice to use the new `dict` list comprehension constructor.

Secondly, while constructing an XML document, it is possible that a child will have multiple parents, although this gets removed once you serialize the document. If that matters, you might try this:

```
parent_map = {}
for p in tree.iter():
    for c in p:
        if c in parent_map:
            parent_map[c].append(p)
            # Or raise, if you don't want to allow this.
        else:
            parent_map[c] = [p]
            # Or parent_map[c] = p if you don't want to allow this
```

Comment: What if you don't have access to the tree?  Like after a .find()

Comment: I don't know of any way to get the root node (and thus parents/ancestors) if you didn't save a reference to it. But I don't understand how `.find()` has anything to do with that.

Comment: i just used `.find()` as an example function that just returns an element

Answer (score 28):

You can use xpath `...` notation in ElementTree.

```
<parent>
     <child id="123">data1</child>
</parent>

xml.findall('.//child[@id="123"]...')
>> [<Element 'parent'>]
```

Comment: This is fantastic solution, works with find() also if you know there's just a single element that you are looking for. Like so: 
`root.find(".//*[@testname='generated_sql']...")`

Comment: I could not find anything about this `...` XPath syntax. What does it do? Are there docs on it?

Comment: @raphinesse `...` expression comes from XPath 1.0.
Python Std Library have limited support for XPath expressions, lxml have more support.

Comment: The code in the answer does work, but I cannot find any reference to this "triple dot" syntax anywhere. It is not mentioned in the XPath 1.0 recommendation.

Comment: What about elements that do not have an `id` attribute?

Comment: @ioannis-filippidis Oh, you just need a valid XPath followed by an ...
You can use any attribute

All children:

`xml.findall('.//child...')`

Some other attribute:

`xml.findall('.//child[@other="123"]...')`

Comment: **Attention:** This code works perfectly with only **two** dots. There is no such thing as "triple dot syntax". It's not [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax), as others mentioned. It's just a combination of `.` (select current node) and `..` (get parent).

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in [Get parent element after using find method (xml.etree.ElementTree)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239435/get-parent-element-after-using-find-method-xml-etree-elementtree) you would have to do an indirect search for parent.
Having xml:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c>data</c>
  <d>data</d>    
 </b>
</a>
```

Assuming you have created etree element into `xml` variable, you can use:

```
 In[1] parent = xml.find('.//c/..')
 In[2] child = parent.find('./c')
```

Resulting in:

```
Out[1]: <Element 'b' at 0x00XXXXXX> 
Out[2]: <Element 'c' at 0x00XXXXXX>
```

Higher parent would be found as:`secondparent=xml.find('.//c/../..')` being `<Element 'a' at 0x00XXXXXX>`

Comment: this is brilliant, would upvote more if I could

Answer (score 7):

Pasting here my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54943960/492336:

I had a similar problem and I got a bit creative. Turns out nothing prevents us from adding the parent info ourselves. We can later strip it once we no longer need it.

```
def addParentInfo(et):
    for child in et:
        child.attrib['__my_parent__'] = et
        addParentInfo(child)

def stripParentInfo(et):
    for child in et:
        child.attrib.pop('__my_parent__', 'None')
        stripParentInfo(child)

def getParent(et):
    if '__my_parent__' in et.attrib:
        return et.attrib['__my_parent__']
    else:
        return None

# Example usage

tree = ...
addParentInfo(tree.getroot())
el = tree.findall(...)[0]
parent = getParent(el)
while parent:
    doSomethingWith(parent)
    parent = getParent(parent)
stripParentInfo(tree.getroot())
```

Answer (score 6):

The XPath '..' selector cannot be used to retrieve the parent node on 3.5.3 nor 3.6.1 (at least on OSX),
eg in interactive mode:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring('<parent><child></child></parent>')
child = root.find('child')
parent = child.find('..') # retrieve the parent
parent is None # unexpected answer True
```

The last answer breaks all hopes...

Answer (score 3):

Got an answer from

https://towardsdatascience.com/processing-xml-in-python-elementtree-c8992941efd2

**Tip: use '...' inside of XPath to return the parent element of the current element.**

```py
for object_book in root.findall('.//*[@name="The Hunger Games"]...'):
    print(object_book)
```

Comment: This is the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/33280875/407651.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/33280875/407651 doesn't say what ... is, This answer does.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lxml, I was able to get the parent element with the following:

```
parent_node = next(child_node.iterancestors())
```

This will raise a `StopIteration` exception if the element doesn't have ancestors - so be prepared to catch that if you may run into that scenario.

Comment: element object in lxml has getparent() method

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions posted so far

- either use XPath… but Python does not support finding ancestors with XPath in general ([see comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170610/access-elementtree-node-parent-node#comment82579096_47803667)),
- or post-process the whole tree after it is built (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170994/4615179) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54944028/4615179))… but this requires parsing and building the whole tree, which might be undesirable with large XML data (e.g. Wikipedia dumps).

If you are parsing XML incrementally, say with [`xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse)
or [`xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLPullParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLPullParser), you can keep track of the current path (up from the root node down to the current node) by tracking the opening and closing of tags (`start` and `end` events). Example:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

current_path = [ ]

for event, elem in ET.iterparse('test.xml', events=['start', 'end']):
    # opening tag:
    if event == 'start':
        current_path.append(elem)
    # closing tag:
    else:
        assert event == 'end'
        assert len(current_path) > 0 and current_path[-1] is elem
        current_path.pop()
        parent = current_path[-1] if len(current_path) > 0 else None
        # `elem` is the current element (fully built),
        # `parent` is its parent (some of its children after `elem`
        # might not have been parsed yet)
        #
        # ... do something ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

f1 = "yourFile"

xmlTree = ET.parse(f1)

for root in xmlTree.getroot():
    print(root.tag)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Another way if just want a single subElement's parent and also known the subElement's xpath.

```
parentElement = subElement.find(xpath+"/..")
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get 'None' - same if i just use `subElement.find('..')`.

Comment: Assumes that a variable called `xpath` already exists, so it's not helpful for most people.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the 19.7.2.2. section: [Supported XPath syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example) ...

Find node's parent using the path:

```
parent_node = node.find('..')
```

Comment: Did you test this? If you were able to make it work, please post a complete code example that demonstrates it. See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170610/access-elementtree-node-parent-node#comment44519212_21963494

Comment: The Python 3 documentation says: "Returns `None` if the path attempts to reach the ancestors of the start element (the element `find` was called on)." (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax).

Comment: Works for me. The best and most consise answer.