# (Python) How to get the level of a node in xml?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

Is there an efficient way to get the level of each node in xml, using the python xml parser? The level of a node can also be determined by counting the closing tags while parsing the xml top-down, however, I need help in that too :). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe this could be an initial idea:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

level = 0

for (event, node) in iterparse( fileName, ['start', 'end', 'start-ns', 'end-ns'] ):

    if event == 'end':
        level -= 1

    if event == 'start':
        level += 1

    # do soething with node ...
```

Comment: Thanks! thats exactly what I was looking for! :), other answers were great, but they intended to find the level of one node, not each node.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "python xml parser" you mean [`xml.etree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). There are other libraries as well (such as [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/)) which can make this job easier, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170994/520779) there's no easy way to access the parent elements using this library. However, the workaround presented there (creating a mapping of parents to the whole tree) is enough to determine the level of any given element:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
# root = ET.fromstring(...)   # Alternative

parent_map = dict((c, p) for p in root.getiterator() for c in p)
def level(node):
    return level(parent_map[node])+1 if node in parent_map else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use minidom and recommend it for these kind of interactions with XML files. You can use the parentNode attribute of an element for this purpose.

```
import xml.dom.minidom as parser

tree = parser.parse('xml.xml')

#let's say we want the first instance of a tag with an specific name
x = tree.getElementsByTagName('tagname')[0]

level = 0
while x:
    x = x.parentNode
    level += 1

print(level)
```

This is a link to [minidom documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).