# Parse hierarchical XML tags

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, ipython

Need to parse hierarchical tags from XML and get the tag's value in desired output

**Input**

```
<doc>
<pid id="231">
    <label key="">Electronics</label>
        <desc/>
        <cid id="122">
        <label key="">TV</label>
        </cid>
        <desc/>
        <cid id="123">
        <label key="">Computers</label>
        <cid id="12433">
            <label key="">Lenovo</label>
            </cid>
            <desc/>
            <cid id="12434">
            <label key="">IBM</label>
            <desc/>
            </cid>
            <cid id="12435">
            <label key="">Mac</label>
            </cid>
            <desc/>
    </cid>
</pid>
<pid id="7764">
    <label key="">Music</label>
    <desc/>
        <cid id="1224">
        <label key="">Play</label>
        <desc/>
            <cid id="341">
            <label key="">PQR</label>
            </cid>
            <desc/>
        </cid>
        <cid id="221">
        <label key="">iTunes</label>
            <cid id="341">
            <label key="">XYZ</label>
            </cid>
            <desc/>
            <cid id="515">
            <label key="">ABC</label>
            </cid>
            <desc/>
        </cid>
</pid>
</doc>
```

**Output**

```
Electornics/
Electornics/TV
Electornics/Computers/Lenovo
Electornics/Computers/IBM
Electornics/Computers/Mac
Music/
Music/Play/PQR
Music/iTunes/XYZ
Music/iTunes/ABC
```

**What I have tried (*in Python*)**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import sys
import string

def perf_func(elem, func, level=0):
    func(elem,level)
    for child in elem.getchildren():
        perf_func(child, func, level+1)

def print_level(elem,level):
    print '-'*level+elem.tag

root = ET.parse('Products.xml')
perf_func(root.getroot(), print_level)

# Added find logic
root = tree.getroot()

for n in root.findall('doc')
  l = n.find('label').text
  print l
```

With the above code, I am able to get the nodes and its levels (just the tag not their value) . And also the 1st level of all labels.
Need some suggestion (Perl/Python) on how to proceed to get the hirerachical structure in the format mentioned in Output.

Comment: Take a look at the etree `find` & `findall` functions, it takes an xpath expression

Comment: Added the find logic (edited the question - what i tried) ... Need some suggestion on how to get the tree structure in the format mentioned in Output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are going to use 3 pieces: find all of the elements in the order in which they occur, get the depth of each one, build a bread crumb based on the depth and order.

```
from lxml import etree
xml = etree.fromstring(xml_str)
elems = xml.xpath(r'//label')  #xpath expression to find all '<label ...> elements

# counts the number of parents to the root element
def get_depth(element):
    depth = 0
    parent = element.getparent()
    while parent is not None:
        depth += 1
        parent = parent.getparent()
    return depth

# build up the bread crumbs by tracking the depth
# when a new element is entered, it replaces the value in the list
# at that level and drops all values to the right
def reduce_by_depth(element_list):
    crumbs = []
    depth = 0
    elem_crumb = ['']*10
    for elem in element_list:
        depth = get_depth(elem)
        elem_crumb[depth] = elem.text
        elem_crumb[depth+1:] = ['']*(10-depth-1)
        # join all the non-empty string to get the breadcrumb
        crumbs.append('/'.join([e for e in elem_crumb if e]))
    return crumbs

reduce_by_depth(elems)

# output:
['Electronics',
 'Electronics/TV',
 'Electronics/Computers',
 'Electronics/Computers/Lenovo',
 'Electronics/Computers/IBM',
 'Electronics/Computers/Mac',
 'Music',
 'Music/Play',
 'Music/Play/PQR',
 'Music/iTunes',
 'Music/iTunes/XYZ',
 'Music/iTunes/ABC']
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can also be solved by [using a custom iterator, similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275524/xml-etree-elementtree-get-node-depth/41536162#41536162)

The code has to keep track of when a new path segment gets added (not every hierarchy level might have a label), so that it can remove them at the right time when we go back up. I do this by storing a tuple of depth and label.

I also assume that you are interested in the parent of every label tag, which is why I check for a label element and then yield back its parent.

The code will work if the label is not the first element. If a tag has multiple labels as direct children, it will return the same parent twice.

```
from lxml import etree

def label_iter(element):
    path = []
    stack = []
    stack.append(iter([element]))
        while stack:
            e = next(stack[-1], None)
            if e == None:
                stack.pop()
                if(len(path) > 0 and len(stack) < path[-1][0]):
                    path.pop()
            else:
                stack.append(iter(e))
                label_tag = e.find('label') 
                if label_tag is not None:
                    path.append((len(stack),label_tag.text))
                if e.tag == 'label':
                    yield (e.getparent(), "/".join([label for debth, label in path]))

tree = etree.fromstring(xml_str)
root = tree.getroot()
for tag, path in label_iter(root):
    print(path)
```

The code works, but I think it can be done with less repetition and in a cleaner way. I do not like the double bookkeeping with the path and stack array and looking for labels twice also seems inelegant. So feel free to improve it!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibe solution is to use recursion. It feels a bit like a tool from a past, darker age, but it allows using the call stack to keep track of the depth instead of having to do that manually.

```
from lxml import etree
MAX_DEPTH = 20

def recursive_parse(element, path = [], depth = 0):
    if depth > MAX_DEPTH:
        return
    label_tag = element.find('label')
    if label_tag is not None: #found new path segment
        path.append(label_tag.text)
        print('/'.join(path))
    for child in element.getchildren():
        recursive_parse(child, path, depth+1)

tree = etree.fromstring(xml_str)
root = tree.getroot()
recursive_parse(root)
```

Instead of printing the path, it could for example be stored in a dict to make it possible to retrieve an element by its path:

```
dict paths = {}
...
       if label_tag is not None: #found new path segment
           path.append(label_tag.text)
           paths['/'.join(path)] = element
```

To me, the solution seems less elegant, but it is shorter and might be easier to understand.