# different return types for getpath() in lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have folders full of XML files which I want to parse to a dataframe. The following functions iterate through an XML tree recursively and return a dataframe with three columns: path, attributes and text.

```py
def XML2DF(filename,df1,MAX_DEPTH=20):
    with open(filename) as f:
        xml_str = f.read()
    tree = etree.fromstring(xml_str)
    df1 = recursive_parseXML2DF(tree, df1, MAX_DEPTH=MAX_DEPTH)
    return 

def recursive_parseXML2DF(element, df1, depth=0, MAX_DEPTH=20):
    if depth > MAX_DEPTH:
        return df1
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([[element.getroottree().getpath(element), element.attrib, element.text]],
                       columns=["path", "attrib", "text"])
    
    #print(df2)
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
    for child in element.getchildren():
        df1 = recursive_parseXML2DF(child, df1, depth=depth + 1)
    return df1
```

The code for the function was adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112938/parse-hierarchical-xml-tags) post.

Most of the times the function works fine and returns the entire path but for some documents the returned path looks like this:

```
/*/*[1]/*[3]
/*/*[1]/*[3]/*[1]
```

The text tag entry remains valid and correct.
The only difference in the XML between working path and widlcard path documents I can make out is that the XML tags are written in all caps.

Working example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Header>
    <ReceivingApplication>ReceivingApplication</ReceivingApplication>
    <SendingApplication>SendingApplication</SendingApplication>
    <MessageControlID>12345</MessageControlID>
    <ReceivingApplication>ReceivingApplication</ReceivingApplication>
    <FileCreationDate>2000-01-01T00:00:00</FileCreationDate>
  </Header>
  <Einsendung>
    <Patient>
      <PatientName>Name</PatientName>
      <PatientVorname>FirstName</PatientVorname>
      <PatientGebDat>2000-01-01T00:00:00</PatientGebDat>
      <PatientSex>4</PatientSex>
      <PatientPWID>123456</PatientPWID>
    </Patient>
    <Visit>
      <VisitNumber>A2000.0001</VisitNumber>
      <PatientPLZ>1234</PatientPLZ>
      <PatientOrt>PatientOrt</PatientOrt>
      <PatientAdr2>
      </PatientAdr2>
      <PatientStrasse>PatientStrasse 01</PatientStrasse>
      <VisitEinsID>1234</VisitEinsID>
      <VisitBefund>VisitBefund</VisitBefund>
      <Befunddatum>2000-01-01T00:00:00</Befunddatum>
    </Visit>
  </Einsendung>
</root>
```

nonsensical Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<KRSCHWEIZ xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="krSCHWEIZ">
  <KEY_VS>abcdefg</KEY_VS>
  <KEY_KLR>abcdefg</KEY_KLR>
  <ABSENDER>
    <ABSENDER_MELDER_ID>123456</ABSENDER_MELDER_ID>
    <MELDER>
      <MELDER_ID>123456</MELDER_ID>
      <QUELLSYSTEM>ABCDEF</QUELLSYSTEM>
      <PATIENT>
        <REFERENZNR>987654</REFERENZNR>
        <NACHNAME>my name</NACHNAME>
        <VORNAMEN>my first name</VORNAMEN>
        <GEBURTSNAME />
        <GEBURTSDATUM>my dob</GEBURTSDATUM>
        <GESCHLECHT>XX</GESCHLECHT>
        <PLZ>9999</PLZ>
        <WOHNORT>Mycity</WOHNORT>
        <STRASSE>mystreet</STRASSE>
        <HAUSNR>99</HAUSNR>
        <VERSICHERTENNR>999999999</VERSICHERTENNR>
        <DATEIEN>
          <DATEI>
            <DATEINAME>my_attached_document.html</DATEINAME>
            <DATEIBASE64>mybase_64_encoded_document</DATEIBASE64>
          </DATEI>
        </DATEIEN>
       </PATIENT>
    </MELDER>
  </ABSENDER>
</KRSCHWEIZ>
```

How do I get correct explicit path information also for this case?

Comment: I added the calling function, reproducible examples will follow

Comment: Ok added xml snippets

Comment: Holy cow that fixes some things !
I get 
`Header/ReceivingApplication[1]   
Header/SendingApplication    
Header/MessageControlID    
Header/ReceivingApplication[2] 
`
For the working xml and:
`{krSCHWEIZ}KEY_VS 
krSCHWEIZ}ABSENDER/{krSCHWEIZ}ABSENDER_MELDER_ID`
for the non working snippet.

Is there a way to have  the returns formatted the same way regardless of what type of xml/namespace or other is in the xml file ?

Comment: That would be splendid.

Answer (score 1):

The prescence of namespaces changes the output of `.getpath()` - you can use `.getelementpath()` instead which will include the namespace prefix instead of using wildcards.

If the prefix should be discarded completely - you can [strip them out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18159221)  before using `.getpath()`

```
import lxml.etree
import pandas as pd

rows = []
tree = lxml.etree.parse("broken.xml")
for node in tree.iter():
    try:
        node.tag = lxml.etree.QName(node).localname
    except ValueError:
        # skip tags with no name
        continue
    rows.append([tree.getpath(node), node.attrib, node.text])
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["path", "attrib", "text"])
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
>>> df
                                                 path attrib                        text
0                                          /KRSCHWEIZ     []                        \n  
1                                   /KRSCHWEIZ/KEY_VS     []                     abcdefg
2                                  /KRSCHWEIZ/KEY_KLR     []                     abcdefg
3                                 /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER     []                      \n    
4              /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/ABSENDER_MELDER_ID     []                      123456
5                          /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER     []                    \n      
6                /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/MELDER_ID     []                      123456
7              /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/QUELLSYSTEM     []                      ABCDEF
8                  /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT     []                  \n        
9       /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/REFERENZNR     []                      987654
10        /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/NACHNAME     []                     my name
11        /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/VORNAMEN     []               my first name
12     /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/GEBURTSNAME     []                        None
13    /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/GEBURTSDATUM     []                      my dob
14      /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/GESCHLECHT     []                          XX
15             /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/PLZ     []                        9999
16         /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/WOHNORT     []                      Mycity
17         /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/STRASSE     []                    mystreet
18          /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/HAUSNR     []                          99
19  /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/VERSICHERTENNR     []                   999999999
20         /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/DATEIEN     []                \n          
21   /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/DATEIEN/DATEI     []              \n            
22  /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/DATEIEN/DAT...     []   my_attached_document.html
23  /KRSCHWEIZ/ABSENDER/MELDER/PATIENT/DATEIEN/DAT...     []  mybase_64_encoded_document
```