# Removing an element, but not the text after it

Tags: python, elementtree

I have an `XML` file similar to this:

```
<root>
<a>Some <b>bad</b> text <i>that</i> I <u>do <i>not</i></u> want to keep.</a>
</root>
```

I want to remove all text in `<b>` or `<u>` elements (and descendants), and print the rest. This is what I tried:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('a.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

parent_map = {c:p for p in root.iter() for c in p}

for item in root.findall('.//b'):
  parent_map[item].remove(item)
for item in root.findall('.//u'):
  parent_map[item].remove(item)
print(''.join(root.itertext()).strip())
```

(I used the recipe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132342/1538701) to build the `parent_map`). The problem, of course, is that with `remove(item)` I'm also removing the text after the element, and the result is:

```
Some that I
```

whereas what I want is:

```
Some  text that I  want to keep.
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you won't end up using anything better, you can use `clear()` instead of `remove()` keeping the tail of the element:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


data = """<root>
<a>Some <b>bad</b> text <i>that</i> I <u>do <i>not</i></u> want to keep.</a>
</root>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
a = tree.find('a')
for element in a:
    if element.tag in ('b', 'u'):
        tail = element.tail
        element.clear()
        element.tail = tail

print ET.tostring(tree)
```

prints (see empty `b` and `u` tags):

```
<root>
<a>Some <b /> text <i>that</i> I <u /> want to keep.</a>
</root>
```

Also, here's a solution using `xml.dom.minodom`:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

data = """<root>
<a>Some <b>bad</b> text <i>that</i> I <u>do <i>not</i></u> want to keep.</a>
</root>"""

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(data)
a = dom.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
for child in a.childNodes:
    if getattr(child, 'tagName', '') in ('u', 'b'):
        a.removeChild(child)

print dom.toxml()
```

prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><root>
<a>Some  text <i>that</i> I  want to keep.</a>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried deleting all text in the elements, but didn't think about saving and restoring the tail. I wouldn't mind changing to a different parser, as long as it's included in standard python distributions.