# Get parent element after using find method (xml.etree.ElementTree)

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am working with a huge xml-file and try to extract information from different elements.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('t.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

To find the elements I use the find method:

```
elm = root.find('.//Element[@elmid="1234"]')
```

From this I extract information and in addition I need information from the parent element. But `elm.find('..')` returns only `None` as documented here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Now I use the folowing:

```
prt = root.find('.//Element[@elmid="1234"]/..')     
elm = prt.find('/Element[@elmid="1234"]')
```

This looks a bit unnatural to me, but works.

Do you know a better way to do this?
Do you know why only `None` is returned?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `xml.etree` API only supports a limited version of XPath. The [`xml.etree` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) for the `..` XPath expression state:

> Selects the parent element. **Returns None if the path attempts to
>   reach the ancestors of the start element (the element find was called
>   on).**

Directly getting the parent element is [not supported in the `xml.etree` API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170994/1599111). I would therefore recommend to use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de), where you can simply use [`getparent()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#getparent) to get the parent element:

```
elm = root.find('.//Element[@elmid="1234"]')
elm.getparent()
```

`lxml` also has a full [XPath 1.0 implementation](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html), so `elem.xpath('..')` would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and I got a bit creative. Turns out nothing prevents us from adding the parentage info ourselves. We can later strip it once we no longer need it.

```
def addParentInfo(et):
    for child in et:
        child.attrib['__my_parent__'] = et
        addParentInfo(child)

def stripParentInfo(et):
    for child in et:
        child.attrib.pop('__my_parent__', 'None')
        stripParentInfo(child)

def getParent(et):
    if '__my_parent__' in et.attrib:
        return et.attrib['__my_parent__']
    else:
        return None

tree = ...
addParentInfo(tree.getroot())
el = tree.findall(...)[0]
parent = getParent(el)
while parent:
    ...
    parent = getParent(parent)
...
stripParentInfo(tree.getroot())
```