# How to extract the parents of xmls tags with python?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

In the example below, I could extract the texts and tags with:

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

 tree = ET.parse(xml_path)
 root = tree.getroot()
 tags=[elem.tag for elem in root.iter()]
 texts=[elem.text for elem in root.iter()]
```

Output:
[image]

How could I get a list with its parents? Something like

```
parents=[elem.tag.parents for elem in root.iter()]
```

Output: 
['\n', 'data', 'country', 'country', 'country', 'country', 'country', 'data', 'country', 'country', 'country', 'country', 'data', 'country', 'country', 'country', 'country', 'country']

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use lxml, which has a `getparent()` method. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239665/407651

Comment: Btw, you should always post XML markup (and code) as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please upload the xml as text and the expected output.