# Reading XML that uses attributes

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, elementtree

A noob question on XML. I am using ElementTree to convert the XML to a df and eventually upload to a database. My problem is that the XML format is not standard. All ElementTree examples that I have seen use a different format. It looks something like this:

```
<session session_id="9">
    <party party_id="1" name="party 1">
        <member member_id="1" name="bob"/>
        <member member_id="2" name="simon"/>
    </party>
    <party party_id="2" name="party 2">
        <member member_id="3" name="diana"/>
        <member member_id="4" name="pablo"/>
    </party>
</session>
```

For one thing, all information is written in attributes, which is not a big issue because I can still fetch them. However I want to pick up the attributes not only of the `member` elements, but also of their parents. So the result should look something like this:

| member_id | member_name | party_id | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bob | 1 | 9 |
| 2 | simon | 1 | 9 |
| 3 | diana | 2 | 9 |
| 4 | pablo | 2 | 9 |

I use `children = list(root.iter())` to list all children and then append their attributes to a dataframe. However I lose the link to parent, so I cannot really say which `party` branch the `member` came from, so I cannot assign the right `party_id`.

I am wondering whether there is an easy way to get a dataframe out of this XML structure?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Show us code in the form of a [mcve]. Regarding getting the parent, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/24239435/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2170610/407651

Comment: Find all the `party` tags and for each one iterate through their `member`, i.e. so you know the parent when looking at a child. Strangely enough there's a `findall()` methind in ElementTree, look at the documentation.

Comment: FYI there's nothing "non-standard" about your XML. It's just... xml.

Comment: Just because you, as a newbie, haven't seen XML like this before doesn't make it "non-standard". You really should be reconsidering your learning strategy: read about the technologies you are using to learn their concepts, rather than being taken by surprise every time you encounter something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


xml = '''<session session_id="9">
    <party party_id="1" name="party 1">
        <member member_id="1" name="bob"/>
        <member member_id="2" name="simon"/>
    </party>
    <party party_id="2" name="party 2">
        <member member_id="3" name="diana"/>
        <member member_id="4" name="pablo"/>
    </party>
</session>'''

data = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
session_id = root.attrib['session_id']
for party in root.findall('party'):
  for memeber in party.findall('member'):
    data.append({'session_id':session_id,'party_id': party.attrib['party_id']})
    data[-1]['member_name'] = memeber.attrib['name']
    data[-1]['member_id'] = memeber.attrib['member_id']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
  session_id party_id member_name member_id
0          9        1         bob         1
1          9        1       simon         2
2          9        2       diana         3
3          9        2       pablo         4
```

Comment: Why to use `-1` index instead of appending element after all data collected?

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is fully valid and well formed, but the example below indicates how xml is usually structured.

```xml
<parent attribute="supporting information">
    Information
    <child attribute="supporting information">
        Information
    </child>
</parent>
```

Alas, ElementTree does not provide a neat way of converting attributes to tag content/information.

**Solution**
You are half-way there (or possibly a third if we count the root element 'session'). You will have to iterate per xml-element level. (e.g. for every party element, iterate every member).

Comment: The XML specification https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/ specifies the syntax of XML, and your example of "supporting information" and "information" is exactly that: an example i.e. it's not part of the specification, e.g. "supporting" isn't in the specification. So XML _doesn't_ specify the distinction you're making - it can be used that way or not that way - both are valid.

Comment: Fair point @balmy, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: As the OP's example perhaps shows, there may not be a "usual" way to structure XML, just different ways that are "usual" or suited for different data and purposes.