# How do i get newest date through xpath?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xpath, xml-parsing

I have next xml:

```
<Content>
<article title="I Compute, Therefore I am" id="a1">
        <authors>
            <author>Philbert von Cookie</author>
            <author>Alice Brockman</author>
            <author>Pedro Smith</author>
        </authors>
        <journal>
            <name>Journal of Computational Metaphysics</name>
            <volume>3</volume>
            <issue>7</issue>
            <published>04/11/2006</published>
            <pages start="42" end="49"/>
        </journal>
</article>
...
</Content>
```

There are a lot of similar article nodes inside the root element -> content

i have parsed my xml into python code and want to get maximum date value. Here is my python code:

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.ElementTree(file='data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root.tag, root.attrib
```

I am trying to get it using iterfind(), but this not works so far.

```
for elem in tree.iterfind('(/*/*/journal/published/value[not(text() < preceding-sibling::value/text()) and not(text() < following-sibling::value/text())])[1]'):
 print (elem.text)
```

Can you please help me with answer how do i set my XPATH for iterfind() or may be there are any other ways to do that?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xml.etree.ElementTree` provides only [limited xpath support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).

One alternative option would be to parse all dates into a list and get the maximum value:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = [published.text for published in root.iterfind('.//article/journal/published')]
print max(dates, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Note that in order to find max value in this case, you should compare `datetime` values, not strings (this is where `key` function helps).

---

Also, if you want to get the corresponding to the max date `journal` record, you can construct a dictionary mapping "date -> journal" and then get the appropriate journal record:

```
from datetime import datetime
import operator

try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.ElementTree(file='data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

mapping = {datetime.strptime(journal.findtext('published'), '%d/%m/%Y'): journal 
           for journal in root.iterfind('.//article/journal')}

journal_latest = max(mapping.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))[1]
print journal_latest.findtext('name')
```

Comment: I can't run the last part of the code. Python says Syntax error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find.py", line 13, in <module>
    for journal in root.iterfind('.//article/journal')}
  File "find.py", line 13, in <dictcomp>
    for journal in root.iterfind('.//article/journal')}
  File "C:\Python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '05/25/2002' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: @DonKorleone the format is not what I was expecting, swap month and day: `%m/%d/%Y` instead of `%d/%m/%Y`.

Comment: And how you use journal.findtext('published')? what is journal? If this is node's name, where it was defined before? Sorry may be this is simple question, but i am new in python. So i would appreciate if you could explain step by step

Comment: If i change date it not matches. So initially it was right

Comment: @DonKorleone well, `05/25/2002` is clearly `%m/%d/%Y`. `journal` is every resulting node found by `.//article/journal` xpath expression. Not sure how to help more - it works for me on the input you've provided.

Comment: Finally it worked. Thank you so much. One last question. What should i do in order to get article's title attribute value?

Comment: @DonKorleone good, glad it helped. Well, in the current state of the code, we don't have a corresponding `article` for each `journal`, and since ElementTree doesn't support getting a parent of a node (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170610/access-elementtree-node-parent-node) - we should change the way we iterate over the nodes. Could you show what is the current code you said is working? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. This code is working now:
from datetime import datetime
import operator

try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.ElementTree(file='data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

mapping = {datetime.strptime(journal.findtext('published'), '%m/%d/%Y'): journal 
           for journal in root.iterfind('.//article/journal')}
     
journal_latest = max(mapping.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))[1]
print (journal_latest.findtext('name'))

Comment: Ok, i was able to get parent node's attribute to print it. Thank you alecxe so much for your help. Appreciate that