# Adding a parent tag to a nested structure with ElementTree (Python)

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
I have the following structure

<root>
  <data>
     <config>
        CONFIGURATION
     <config>
  </data>

</root>
```

With Python's ElementTree module I want to add a parent element to `<config>` tag as

```
<root>
  <data>
    <type>
      <config>
        CONFIGURATION
      <config>
    </type>
  </data>

</root>
```

Also the xml file might have other config tags elsewhere but I'm only interested in the ones appearing under data tag.

Comment: "under data tag" -- Do you mean direct children, or would a "grandchild" still be picked up?

Comment: direct children under data tag.

Comment: and what code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This boils down to ~3 steps:

1. get the elements that match your criteria (tag == x, parent tag == y)
2. remove that element from the parent, putting a new child in that place
3. add the former child to the new child.

For the first step, we can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170994/748858).  Since we know we'll need the parent later, let's keep that too in our search.

```
def find_elements(tree, child_tag, parent_tag):
    parent_map = dict((c, p) for p in tree.iter() for c in p)
    for el in tree.iter(child_tag):
        parent = parent_map[el]
        if parent.tag == parent_tag:
            yield el, parent
```

steps two and three are pretty related, we can do them together.

```
def insert_new_els(tree, child_tag, parent_tag, new_node_tag):
    to_replace = list(find_elements(tree, child_tag, parent_tag))
    for child, parent in to_replace:
        ix = list(parent).index(child)
        new_node = ET.Element(new_node_tag)
        parent.insert(ix, new_node)
        parent.remove(child)
        new_node.append(child)
```

Your tree will be modified in place.
Now usage is simply:

```
tree = ET.parse('some_file.xml')
insert_new_els(tree, 'config', 'data', 'type')
tree.write('some_file_processed.xml')
```

<sup>*untested*</sup>

Comment: That was indeed a great answer