# How do I remove a node in xml using ElementTree in Python by searching attributes of an element?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

**Sample xml file:**

```
<root>
   <child1 />
   <child2 bksetname="Default Backup Set" />
   <child3 bksetname="Local Backup Set" />
</root>
```

**Code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tr = ET.parse("Scheduler.xml")
for elem in tr.iter():
    print elem.tag , elem.attrib
    if elem.attrib.get('bksetname') == "Default Backup Set":
        elem.remove(elem.tag)
```

**Output:**

```
Entering elem:
self._children.remove(element)
child2
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I am trying to delete the element by searching the element in file, if it has the attribute I want.I tried this way in my code and getting error in my output as shared.
Please tell me how can I do this using xml.etree.ElementTree package.

Comment: correct `Default` in your `scheduler.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove it from the element which you are iterating. Here `tr` is a `ElementTree` type object. If you want to remove some element from the tree, you can do it by removing it from the root element. Something Like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tr = ET.parse("Scheduler.xml")
for elem in tr.iter():
    print elem.tag , elem.attrib
    if elem.attrib.get('bksetname') == "Default Backup Set":
        tr.getroot().remove(elem)

# for rewriting the file:
tr.write("Scheduler.xml")
```

Comment: could you find the reason?

Comment: @Juna i was making a mistake, as i did not tried the code. sorry for that. Check my edit now please.

Comment: It still does not remove the element from file whose attribute is " bksetname='Default Backup Set' "

Comment: @Juna It should work. I've tested it. do want to delete the element from the `Scheduler.xml` file also?

Comment: Yes Salman my purpose is to delete it from the file I read it from.   @salman I cannot reply on comments after some number as I dont have that privilege in StackOverFlow as yet...

Answer (score 1):

For doing so you need to access item's parent. If you are sure it alwasy one level deep, yo can remove it directly by using:

```
tr.remove(item)
```

But if not, you need to create a reverse tree to access parent, like describe [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170994/501979), Or you can use more powerful library like [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Then you can use `xpath` and `getparent` to handle the issue.

The correct way to handle this query is using XPATH:

```
from lxml import etree
tr = etree.fromstring(open("Scheduler.xml").read())
for item in tr.xpath(//*[@bksetname="Default Backup Set"]):
    item.getparent().remove(item)
```

Pattern `//*[@bksetname="Default Backup Set"]` means all element which has attribute bksetname="Default Backup Set". Then we ask for it's parent and remove the element.

*Please mention I use lxml instead of ElementTree.*

You can use [Free OnlineXpath tester](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) for checking `XPATH`

Comment: elegant approach. lxml is more powerful. I also suggest this. +1