# python xml - why find("..") doesn't return root

Tags: python, xml

Why doesn't `element.find("..")` return `root` when `root.findall("*")` returns `element`?

```
def XML_Extract_Node_Tags(Tree, Node_Tags):
    """
    :param Tree: xml.etree.ElementTree
    :param Node_Tags: list
    :return: ReturnVal:
    """

    for el in Tree.findall("//"):
        if el.tag not in Node_Tags:
            print(el.tag)
            # Need to remove the element and set its children equal to parent
            for subel in el.findall("*"):
                ## Add subel to grandparent (if exists)
                grand_parent = subel.find('../..')
                if grand_parent:
                    # If it has a grand parent
                    grand_parent.append(subel)
            # Remove el from tree
            if not el.find(".."):
                print(el.tag, el.attrib)
            else:
                el.find("..").remove(el)

    ReturnVal = Tree
    return ReturnVal
```

First 5 lines of XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE build SYSTEM "build.dtd">
<build id="58" localAgents="true" cm="usl000348:80" start="6/1/2016 3:31:19 PM">
<properties>
<property name="CommandLine">emake all --emake-annodetail=waiting,registry,md5,lookup,history,file,env --emake-annofile=../Emake-2agents-1st.xml --emake-root=../</property>
```

Comment: `el.find('..')` means "in all child elements of this element, find the parent", right?  Wouldn't that just point back to the element itself, instead of the element's parent?

Comment: @JohnGordon touche. Yes you're right: [Finds the first **subelement** matching match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170610/access-elementtree-node-parent-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `xml.etree.ElementTree` implementation doesn't record the parent of an `Element`. Consequently, [the documentation for XPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) includes this:

> `..`  Selects the parent element. Returns `None` if the path attempts to reach the ancestors of the start element (the element find was called on).

Comment: `lxml.etree.ElementTree` does keep track of parents, and may be a good alternative. I tested OPs syntax and it works as expected.

Comment: I was going to add that info to my answer, but couldn't word it right and find the right doc link. Feel free to edit, if you want.