# XML remove nodes with no attributes or children

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree, xml.etree

I have an xml file loaded, from which I want to remove elements that have no attributes or children, I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
for child in root.find('targetElement'):
    print(child)
    if(len(child.attrib) < 1 and len(child) < 1):
        root.remove(child)
```

But I guess the problem is that I'm finding the element then trying to remove it from the root element. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove a node from its parent, not from the root.

The following code works for `lxml.etree`:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

root = ET.parse('yourfile.xml')

for child in root.iterfind('targetElement'):
    if(len(child.attrib) < 1 and len(child) < 1):
        child.getparent().remove(child)
```

The standard `xml.etree.ElementTree` lacks any decent method of selecting the parent node. We can work around this limitation by constructing a child-to-parent map for the entire tree ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132342/18771)):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('yourfile.xml')

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132342/18771
parent_map = {c:p for p in root.iter() for c in p}

for child in root.iterfind('targetElement'):
    if(len(child.attrib) < 1 and len(child) < 1):
        parent_map[child].remove(child)
```

Comment: Sorry, what am I missing? AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getparent'

Comment: `getparent()` is available in lxml, but not in the standard library ElementTree module.

Comment: @mao I see. Try `child.findall('..')[0].remove(child)`.

Comment: thanks but another issue child.findall('..')[0].remove(child)
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @mao It seems support for selecting the parent node in elementtree is more broken than I thought. Look at the modified answer. Also note that I use `iterfind()` instead of `find()`

Comment: I'm voting to downvote this question because the answer doesn't work.