# Navigating Upwards in XML file using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

I have an XML file which looks like this

```
<tagset>
  <image>
    <imageName>apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG</imageName>
    <resolution x="1600" y="1200" />
    <taggedRectangles>
      <taggedRectangle x="174.0" y="392.0" width="274.0" height="195.0" offset="0.0" rotation="0.0" userName="admin" />
      <taggedRectangle x="512.0" y="391.0" width="679.0" height="183.0" offset="0.0" rotation="0.0" userName="admin" />
      <taggedRectangle x="184.0" y="612.0" width="622.0" height="174.0" offset="-2.0" rotation="0.0" userName="admin" />
      <taggedRectangle x="863.0" y="599.0" width="446.0" height="187.0" offset="0.0" rotation="0.0" userName="admin" />
      <taggedRectangle x="72.0" y="6.0" width="95.0" height="87.0" offset="0.0" rotation="0.0" userName="admin" />
      <taggedRectangle x="247.0" y="2.0" width="197.0" height="88.0" offset="0.0" rotation="0.0" userName="admin" />
      <taggedRectangle x="792.0" y="0.0" width="115.0" height="81.0" offset="0.0" rotation="0.0" userName="admin" />
      <taggedRectangle x="200.0" y="848.0" width="228.0" height="139.0" offset="0.0" rotation="0.0" userName="admin" />
      <taggedRectangle x="473.0" y="878.0" width="165.0" height="109.0" offset="14.0" rotation="0.0" userName="admin" />
      <taggedRectangle x="684.0" y="878.0" width="71.0" height="106.0" offset="12.0" rotation="0.0" userName="admin" />
      <taggedRectangle x="806.0" y="844.0" width="218.0" height="141.0" offset="26.0" rotation="0.0" userName="admin" />
    </taggedRectangles>
  </image>
</tagset>
```

I want to access the `<imageName>` tag after I reach a `<taggedRectangle>` tag.
I wrote the following code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
with open('locations.xml','r') as file:
    contents = file.read()

tree = ET.fromstring(contents)  #tree represents the root node of the xml file which is tagset
tags = tree.findall(".//taggedRectangle")
attribs = ['x','y','width','height']
x = []
y = []
width = []
height = []
imageName = []

for tag in tags:
    x.append(tag.get('x'))
    y.append(tag.get('y'))
    width.append(tag.get('width'))
    height.append(tag.get('height'))
    print(type(tag))
    print(tag.tag)
    temp = tag.find('./..') ####THIS LINE IS BEING REFERRED AFTERWARDS####
    print(type(temp))
```

Now, in the line I have highlighted above, I expect `temp` to be referring to the `<taggedRectangles`> node. But it shows me type `NoneType`. Why?

(locations.xml refers to the name of the xml file in my device, the content of which is like the XML file in the beginning of the question)

Note - https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html According to the documentation, my syntax seems valid to me, but I can't figure out the error.

Comment: See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2170610/407651. It is actually a bit confusing. Some of the answers contradict each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `temp = tag.find('./..')` (using *ElementTree*) is not likely to get
the parent element.
Open *The ElementTree XML API* site (mentioned in your post) and find
*Supported XPath syntax*. Description of *..* reads:
*Returns None if the path attempts to reach the ancestors of the start element*.

I think the proper recipe to your problem is to use *lxml* instead of
*ElementTree*, as it contains some methods and functionality missing in
*ElementTree*.

I tried the below code:

```
from lxml import etree as et

root = et.XML(contents)   # contents contains your XML
for elem in root.findall('.//taggedRectangle'):
    x = elem.get('x')
    pic = elem.xpath('../../imageName')[0].text
    print(x, pic)
```

and got the following result:

```
174.0 apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG
512.0 apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG
184.0 apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG
863.0 apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG
72.0 apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG
247.0 apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG
792.0 apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG
200.0 apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG
473.0 apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG
684.0 apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG
806.0 apanar_06.08.2002/IMG_1261.JPG
```

As you can see, e.g. in *xpath* method you are free to use double dots in
*XPath* expressions, without limitations imposed by *ElementTree*.
But this method is present only in *lxml*.