# Python ElementTree filter categories within children xml list with findall

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I would like to work with the [European Transparancy Register](https://data.europa.eu/euodp/en/data/dataset/transparency-register) with Python, however, I had some troubles so far. Below you will find a very simplified version of the XML (which normally contains 1.6 million lines).

I would like to retrieve all the companies that have ticked the category `Digital economy and society` in their `interests`.

However, I am having great difficulty using the `findall()` of `ElementTree` with this very particular XML structure. You can find below an excerpt of my code with the first results I was able to obtain. The filter returns nothing.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ListOfIRPublicDetail xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://intragate.ec.europa.eu/transparencyregister/intws/20200626">
  <metaData>
    <exportDate>2021-01-21T12:20:00.122+01:00</exportDate>
    <numberOfIR>12205</numberOfIR>
  </metaData>
  <resultList>
    <interestRepresentative>
      <name>
        <originalName>F. Hoffmann-La Roche Ltd</originalName>
      </name>
      <interests>
        <interest index="1">
          <name>Budget</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="2">
          <name>Business and Industry</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="3">
          <name>Climate Action</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="4">
          <name>Competition</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="5">
          <name>Consumers</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="6">
          <name>Digital economy and society</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="7">
          <name>Economy, finance and the euro</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="8">
          <name>Environment</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="9">
          <name>External Relations</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="10">
          <name>Institutional affairs</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="11">
          <name>International co-operation and development</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="12">
          <name>Justice and Fundamental Rights</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="13">
          <name>Public Health</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="14">
          <name>Research and innovation</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="15">
          <name>Single market</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="16">
          <name>Trade</name>
        </interest>
      </interests>
    </interestRepresentative>
    <interestRepresentative>
      <name>
        <originalName>Nickel Institute</originalName>
      </name>
      <interests>
        <interest index="1">
          <name>Business and Industry</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="2">
          <name>Climate Action</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="3">
          <name>Consumers</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="4">
          <name>Economy, finance and the euro</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="5">
          <name>Employment and Social Affairs</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="6">
          <name>Energy</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="7">
          <name>Environment</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="8">
          <name>Food Safety</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="9">
          <name>Public Health</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="10">
          <name>Research and innovation</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="11">
          <name>Single market</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="12">
          <name>Trade</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="13">
          <name>Transport</name>
        </interest>
      </interests>
    </interestRepresentative>
  </resultList>
</ListOfIRPublicDetail>
```

```py
    try:
        register_tree = ET.parse(REGISTER_XML)
        register_root = register_tree.getroot()
    except:
        sys.exit("""⚠️ Impossible d'ouvrir le registre. \n\n""")

    # Get all companies name
    for xml in register_root.findall(".//{*}resultList/"):
        print(xml.find("{*}name/{*}originalName").text)
    
    print('\n=============\n')

    # Get categories of interest
    for xml in register_root.findall(".//{*}resultList/"):
        for child in xml.findall("{*}interests/{*}interest/{*}name"):
            print(child.text)
        print('\n')
    
    print('\n=============\n')

    # Filter categories
    for xml in register_root.findall(".//{*}resultList/{*}interests/{*}interest/[{*}name='Digital economy and society']"):
        print(xml)
```

```sh
F. Hoffmann-La Roche Ltd
Nickel Institute

=============

Budget
Business and Industry
Climate Action
Competition
Consumers
Digital economy and society
Economy, finance and the euro
Environment
External Relations
Institutional affairs
International co-operation and development
Justice and Fundamental Rights
Public Health
Research and innovation
Single market
Trade


Business and Industry
Climate Action
Consumers
Economy, finance and the euro
Employment and Social Affairs
Energy
Environment
Food Safety
Public Health
Research and innovation
Single market
Trade
Transport



=============
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170610/access-elementtree-node-parent-node)...

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ListOfIRPublicDetail xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://intragate.ec.europa.eu/transparencyregister/intws/20200626">
  <metaData>
    <exportDate>2021-01-21T12:20:00.122+01:00</exportDate>
    <numberOfIR>12205</numberOfIR>
  </metaData>
  <resultList>
    <interestRepresentative>
      <name>
        <originalName>F. Hoffmann-La Roche Ltd</originalName>
      </name>
      <interests>
        <interest index="1">
          <name>Budget</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="2">
          <name>Business and Industry</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="3">
          <name>Climate Action</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="4">
          <name>Competition</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="5">
          <name>Consumers</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="6">
          <name>Digital economy and society</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="7">
          <name>Economy, finance and the euro</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="8">
          <name>Environment</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="9">
          <name>External Relations</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="10">
          <name>Institutional affairs</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="11">
          <name>International co-operation and development</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="12">
          <name>Justice and Fundamental Rights</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="13">
          <name>Public Health</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="14">
          <name>Research and innovation</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="15">
          <name>Single market</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="16">
          <name>Trade</name>
        </interest>
      </interests>
    </interestRepresentative>
    <interestRepresentative>
      <name>
        <originalName>Nickel Institute</originalName>
      </name>
      <interests>
        <interest index="1">
          <name>Business and Industry</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="2">
          <name>Climate Action</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="3">
          <name>Consumers</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="4">
          <name>Economy, finance and the euro</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="5">
          <name>Employment and Social Affairs</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="6">
          <name>Energy</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="7">
          <name>Environment</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="8">
          <name>Food Safety</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="9">
          <name>Public Health</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="10">
          <name>Research and innovation</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="11">
          <name>Single market</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="12">
          <name>Trade</name>
        </interest>
        <interest index="13">
          <name>Transport</name>
        </interest>
      </interests>
    </interestRepresentative>
  </resultList>
</ListOfIRPublicDetail>
'''

f = StringIO(data)
tree = ET.parse(f)

ns = {'ns': 'http://intragate.ec.europa.eu/transparencyregister/intws/20200626'}

for e in tree.findall('.//*[.="Digital economy and society"]../../../ns:name/ns:originalName', namespaces=ns):
    print(e.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't think I could have found this without your help! Answer validated and upvoted!