# Get Parent XML Element with XML ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Is there a smooth way to access the parent element of an element

For example:

```
<A>
   <B id="254">
      <Z>12.34</Z>
      <C>Lore</C>
      <D>9</D>
   </B>
</A>
```

For `<B>` I want to get `<A>` and for `<Z>, <C>, <D>` I want to get `<B>`

Comment: Looks like the sentence is not terminated `For I want to get and for , , I want to get `

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to insert, now it should be added

Comment: You forgot python tag too -_-

Comment: Doesn't the elementtree tag indicate Python ?!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2170610/407651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the XPath abbreviated syntax `..`.

This would be something like:

```xml
.//B/..
```

(It starts with `.` because ElementTree doesn't allow an absolute path on an element.)

Example:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """
<A>
   <B id="254">
      <Z>12.34</Z>
      <C>Lore</C>
      <D>9</D>
   </B>
</A>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

for elem_name in ['B', 'Z']:
    # Example xpath: .//Z/..
    print(f"Parent of '{elem_name}': " + root.find(f".//{elem_name}/..").tag)
```

This prints:

```
Parent of 'B': A
Parent of 'Z': B
```

If you could use lxml, it has the handy method [`getparent()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html) (plus full xpath 1.0 support and support of exslt extensions).