# Python - How to return parent name when a certain string is found in XML

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file and i am searching looking for a specific string in it. when that string is found, i want to return it's parent name. here is my xml:

```
<context>
    <name>AccuCapacityApp</name>
    <message>
        <source>Capacity</source>
        <translation type="unfinished">Kapazität</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <source>Charge Level</source>
        <translation type="unfinished"></translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <source>Sel (Yes)</source>
        <translation type="unfinished">Sel (Ja)</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <source>Esc (No)</source>
        <translation type="unfinished">Esc (Nein)</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```

I want to search for "unfinished" and return "Capacity" as "source" and "AccuCapacityApp" as "Main".

i tried this but it prints nothing:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

file = "work.xml"

tree = ET.parse(file)
for elem in tree.findall('context/message'):
   found = elem.get('unfinished')
   print(found.attrib)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating all `message` nodes using `tree.findall('context/message')` but you need the `translation` nodes (they hold the `type` attribute). So this will work as a subsitute to your code:

```
for message in tree.iterfind('.//translation[@type="unfinished"]/..'):
    print(message.attrib)
```

It will iterate the `message` nodes caontaining a child `translation` with attribute `type` that equals to `undefined`. For more guidance please read about [XPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) in Python docs. Notice I used `iterfind` which is more efficient.

Next, for achieving what you want you will need to use `message` in order to extract `source`:

```
for message in tree.iterfind('.//translation[@type="unfinished"]/..'):
    print("Source: ", message.find('source').text)
```

In order to get the `name` tag you will need to get the parent of `message`. For that see [this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374245/how-to-retrieve-the-parent-node-using-celementtree). Or just get the that tag from `tree` (`tree.find('./name')`).

Good luck.

Comment: Printing sources works accurately. But I have tried printing `print("Source: ", tree.find('./name'))` , but it prints "None". I have visited the link you have given here. I am not sure which answer to follow.  `tree.find('.//b/..')` also returns "None". The most voted answer contains another for loop. How should I include that with this one?

Comment: I have figured it out how to do that . After mapping the parent with `parent_map = dict((c, p) for p in tree.getiterator() for c in p)`, I printed the parent with `parent_map[message].find('name').text`. Thanks for the help.